# Set a one bit in an 8-bit PIN without changing the other bits

Tags: c, assembly, bit-manipulation, winavr, motordriver

Using winAVR for the following code.

I got an 8-bit PIN here that I need to OR it with 00000010 or 0x02 to set the 7th bit.

Now what I have to do is the following :

- Set Port B bit 7
- Wait for 1ms
- Clear port B bit 7
- wait 19ms

BUT, I shouldn't change the other bits in these steps.

So I have to :

- Read port B
- Set bit needed
- write the modified value back to the port
- Clear bits
- Write back to Port B

So my test code is :

```
B=PINB|0x02
Loop delay for 1ms
BP=PINB&0x00
Loop for 19ms
```

But I think that the other bits are going to be altered in this process, my question is, HOW am I supposed to manipulate one bit of an 8 bit port without changing the other bits ?

Thanks alot !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `BP=PINB & ~0x02`  The ~ operator is logical NOT.  The and operator keeps only the bits *other* than 2.

Answer (score 1):

You use the bitwise negation of the setting mask, and AND that:

```
B = PINB & ~0x02
```

For the selected bit, the bitwise negation sets that bit to zero; all the others are one.
The ones do not change the value in PINB when ANDed.

Comment: Thank you for answering, both of you explained it well but Ben replied first.

Answer (score 0):

This page has a good summary of several tricks with bitwise operators. http://www.catonmat.net/blog/low-level-bit-hacks-you-absolutely-must-know